# How to make Discord.py detect uppercase and lowercase word format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

OK, so I am working on a say command in Discord.py. I want it to detect if the user use bad word that in my banned.txt list, it won't say it. The problem is, how to make it detect uppercase and lowercase letter? For example, in my list, it has "nigga", but the user use "NiGGa". How to make the BOT detect it and won't let the bot say that?
This is my code so far:

````
    @commands.command()
    async def say(self, message, *, content):
      fp  = open('banned.txt')
      bad_list = [word.strip() for line in fp.readlines() for word in line.split(',') if word.strip() if word.lower()]
      if any(word in content for word in bad_list):
          await message.reply("Don't you dare!")
      else:
          await message.channel.trigger_typing()
          await message.reply(f"```{content}```")
````

I can't upload the banned.txt here, as it violate the ToS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the word in lowercase. Take the string and put this.

Try making this: `content=content.lower()` or just making the if statement use content.lower() whenever checking. It'll replace StAckOverFlow to stackoverflow.

So if you're trying to ban the word "Stackoverflow", you don't have to think about every possible sequence, just think of it in lowercase.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This work for me now, but can you explain me what does the function ```lower()``` do in this case?

Comment: It takes a string makes all of it's characters lowercase. For example, it will make "DoGs" to "dogs", and "catS" will be "cats".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Creating a seperate file for those words, Create a list of Bad Words within the code. Another method is, In the above code, In the 4th line, just add `.decode('utf-8')`. This might work.

Comment: You mean something like this?
```bad_list = [word.strip() for line in fp.readlines() for word in line.split(',') if word.strip() if word.lower().decode('utf-8')```